# More performant to use Text or UIImage for title in UINavigationItem

Tags: ios, uinavigationitem

I've seen code which uses an image with text as a title using UIImageView as well as adding a titleView (UIView) with UILabel.

Would the UILabel version be a little bit more efficient than using an image?

Answer (score 2):

Any performance issues should be relatively trivial and unnoticeable. However this isn't just a matter of performance, but many other considerations such as image scaling, memory footprint of the image, localization (image cannot be translated), unnecessary code (adding 5-10 lines of code to use an image), quick editability (image has to be edited in Photoshop vs text can be changed anytime in Xcode). If possible, stick with text. However if you have a very strong branding requirement (e.g. Nike logo), use an image.